# HTTPClient returns 400 Bad Request but Postman returns 201 in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code for a post request

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task<Tuple<int, string>> PostRequestAdditionalAttributeValid0000()
    {
        string locationPath = solutionDirectory.ToString();
        var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(locationPath + @"\TestJsons\testdata.json");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            //Add client header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_uuid", "2fd77dd8-ed76-4bba-b0e1-5cda454c8d6e");

            var result = await client.PostAsync(urlPost, content);

            int StatusNumber = (int)result.StatusCode;
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return new Tuple<int, string>(StatusNumber, resultContent);
        }
    }
```

and in Postman it returns a 201 but HTTPClient returns a 400 response (Bad Request). I have no idea why.

My json is as follows

```
{       
    "audit_date": "2020-05-13T11:27:10.3187798Z",
    "client_uuid": "2fd77dd8-ed76-4bba-b0e1-5cda454c8d6e",
    "audit_entry": {
        "where_uri": "test.com/apps/171f0841-825b-4964-8f8c-0869650f14a6",
        "why_uri": "test.com/reference/reasons_for_change/61acc173-7168-4ae5-9f04-afa228941f8b",
        "who_uri": "test.com/users/4977dae1-a307-425f-980c-53413fef1b0f",
        "when_audited": "2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00",
        "what_uri": "test.com/tests/1bc67a71-8549-4ab8-9dd9-e44238198860",
        "what_changed": [
            {
                "attribute_name": "birth_year",
                "attribute_value": "1969",
                "attribute_change": null
            },
            {
                "attribute_name": "subject_reference",
                "attribute_value": "TEST-WOO3444",
                "attribute_change": null
            }
        ]
    }    
}
```

Any help much appreciated. I've googled and read other similar questions, even tried solutions from other stackoverflow posts but none seem to work.

This is the error I am getting alongside the 400 Bad request

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

After stepping through this line of code

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(urlPost, content);
```

Comment: Use [Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to capture the RAW http request and compare them to see the difference. You can also paste both requests here so we can help you!

Comment: Thanks Simon, I've not used Fiddler before and am quite new to api json automation. The above json is what I am posting to the Post endpoint url, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, this is only the body of the HTTP request. Fiddler is a local proxy that you can use to take a look at the actual HTTP requests sent out by your webbrowser, fiddler, ... . That way you can compare what's different between both requests and can analyze what makes it fail. With the current information given in the question likely no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Check first request in sniffer and compare headers in c# and Postman.  The default headers in c# are not the same as Postman.  Make the c# headers look like Postman.

Comment: Is the server giving any error message besides the status code? can you export for instance a cURL representation of the working request from postman and add it to the question? Probably you are missing some header. Do you have control over the server you are posting to? You could try debugging there ...

Comment: And just as a sidenote: You are not supposed to create a new `HttpClient` for every request, but reuse a previously created instance https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: hi yes i just updated the post, I get  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   after line    var result = await client.PostAsync(urlPost, content);

Comment: You get this as error message from the server or the client is throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the ideas, turns out my json was slightly different for postman and my code, so the 400 bad request was actually the correct outcome for the json I was passing in. (I missed a mandatory field)

Sorry for the trouble.